# No icons, no graphics ubuntu mate

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

I installed ubuntu mate 16.04 on virtual box. All has worked until last software update. virtual box machine shutdown unexpectedly and after a restart I get this graphic:
[image]
I also get ubuntu-mate-welcome error (unrecognized file format png)

How can I solve without reinstall all?

Comment: So any solution found?

Comment: I reinstalled the OS, since it was a fresh Installation

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution would be reinstalling all MATE components with commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate \
     ubuntu-mate-desktop^ ubuntu-mate-artwork ubuntu-mate-default-settings \
     ubuntu-mate-icon-themes ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-complete human-theme \
     gir1.2-mate-panel libmate-desktop-2-17 libmate-menu2 \
     libmate-panel-applet-4-1 libmate-sensors-applet-plugin0 \
     libmate-slab0 libmate-window-settings1 mate-accessibility-profiles \
     mate-applet-topmenu mate-applets mate-applets-common mate-backgrounds \
     mate-control-center mate-control-center-common mate-desktop \
     mate-desktop-common mate-desktop-environment-core mate-dock-applet \
     mate-gnome-main-menu-applet mate-icon-theme mate-icon-theme-faenza \
     mate-indicator-applet mate-indicator-applet-common mate-media \
     mate-media-common mate-menu mate-menus mate-netbook \
     mate-netbook-common mate-netspeed mate-netspeed-common \
     mate-notification-daemon mate-notification-daemon-common \
     mate-optimus mate-panel mate-panel-common mate-polkit \
     mate-polkit-common mate-power-manager mate-power-manager-common \
     mate-screensaver mate-screensaver-common mate-sensors-applet \
     mate-sensors-applet-common mate-session-manager mate-settings-daemon \
     mate-settings-daemon-common mate-system-monitor \
     mate-system-monitor-common mate-terminal mate-terminal-common \
     mate-themes mate-tweak mate-user-guide mate-utils mate-utils-common \
     plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-text \
     python-mate-menu ubuntu-mate-artwork ubuntu-mate-default-settings \
     ubuntu-mate-icon-themes ubuntu-mate-libreoffice-draw-icons \
     ubuntu-mate-lightdm-theme ubuntu-mate-themes ubuntu-mate-wallpapers \
     ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-common ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-complete \
     ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-utopic ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-vivid \
     ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-wily ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-xenial
```

I collected this list on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS MATE system.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Before any software change, I would suggest the check your settings.
Which "Appearance" theme are you currently using?

Having same issue, I realized my ubuntu mate was using a "Custom" theme, without icons at all :)

So, "Menu"> "Control Center" > "Appereance" > "Set a new theme" did the job for me.

[image]